# Example of sets A,B and C, such that A is in B, B is in C and A is not in C

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to bring an example of sets A, B and C, such that

$A \in B, B \in C$ and $A \notin C$

However, I don't get, if every element of set A is in set B and every element of set B is in set C, then every element of set A is in set C, so in my opinion, there is no such example. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Hint: transitive property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \in B$ does not mean that every element in $A$ is an element of $B$. Rather, it means that set $A$, as a whole, is an element of $B$.

So, for example, if $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$, and $B = \{ \{1 ,2 \}, \{ 3,4\}\}$, then $A \in B$, since $\{ 1, 2 \} \in \{ \{1 ,2 \}, \{ 3,4\}\}$

Once you understand this, it should be easy to come up with an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: So if I take A={1,2}, B={{1,2},{3,4}} and C={{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}}, will it work?

Comment: @AregKarapetyan Not quite ... since with that $B \not \in C$ since $C$ has only $1$ element: $\{ \{ 1,2\}, \{ 3,4 \} , \{ 5,6 \} \}$  ... but $C = \{ \{ \{ 1,2 \} , \{ 3,4\} \}, \{ 5,6\}\}$ would work .. do you see the difference?

Comment: Yes, now I get it, thak you very much!

Comment: @AregKarapetyan You're welcome! :)